# Spring WebTestClient response object is different from expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a controller unit test using WebTestClient and it's failing on the `isEqualTo()` test. I can't find what's wrong as I'm using the same object to set what the service call will return and the parameter for `isEqualTo()`

When I run the test I'm getting something like

```
Expected :com.model.Response@ab41b46
Actual   :com.model.Response@c1dcdb9
```

Model: This is just a portion of it but the other objects are just Strings

```
public class Response implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //random long
    private String id;
    private Long amount;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private String status;

    //setters-getters
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<Response> getResponse() {
     return myService.getResponse();
}
```

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private transient WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    private transient MyService myService;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnResponse() {
        var response = new Response();
        response.id("id");
        response.setAmount(10L);
        when(myService.getResponse()).thenReturn(Mono.just(response));
        webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(Response.class)
                .isEqualTo(response);
    }
}
```

As you can see I stubbed myService to return a Mono of `response` and just expected the same on `isEqualTo()`

I have some similar tests to this and they're working fine. I'm currently checking if this is an issue with the `Response` object

Comment: `isEqualTo` uses the `equals` method. Judging from what you have posted here you haven't implemented the `equals` method. No `equals` method means it will use the default which is basically checking if it is the same object instance. Which obviously isn't `true`. Hence either implement a proper `equals` method or use a different way of asserting your result.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, that was it. The object is part of a dependency and I didn't check how the owner implemented it. You can post this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isEqualTo` uses the `equals` method to verify if objects are equal.

Judging from what you have posted here you haven't implemented the `equals` method. No `equals` method means it will use the default which is basically checking if it is the same object instance. Which obviously isn't true.

Hence either implement a proper `equals` method or use a different way of asserting your result.

```java
@Test
void shouldReturnResponse() {
    var response = new Response();
    response.id("id");
    response.setAmount(10L);
    when(myService.getResponse()).thenReturn(Mono.just(response));
    webTestClient.post()
            .uri("/")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody(Response.class)
            .consumeWith( (response) -> assertThat(response.getId()).isEqualTo("id"));}
```

The snippet above uses AssertJ to do the assert (ofcourse you can extend those as well). To do other validations there are other methods on the `BodySpec` as well, pick the one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a mono object with the response object in it. Then you fetch it from your WebTestClient. You're isEqualTo compares the two Objects, which aren't exactly the same object -> mono -> object. I would suggest to compare the values inside the objects.

```
Mono<Response> clientResponse = webTestClient.post()
            .uri("/")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody(Response.class);

 assertThat(clientResponse.block().getId()).isEqualTo("id");
 assertThat(clientResponse.block().response.getAmount()).isEqualTo(10L);
```